# SQL Case and LIKE in where clause

Tags: sql, search, switch-statement, case, sql-like

I have been breaking my head over this hope it's possible

```
declare @locationType varchar(50);
declare @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT column1, column2
FROM whatever
WHERE
CASE @locationType
    WHEN 'location' THEN account_location LIKE @SearchTerm
    WHEN 'area' THEN Area LIKE @SearchTerm
    WHEN 'division' THEN xxx_location_division LIKE @SearchTerm
END
```

I copied the code form another related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause).

I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare @locationType varchar(50);
declare @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT column1, column2
FROM whatever
WHERE
   (@locationType = 'location' AND account_location LIKE @SearchTerm)
OR
   (@locationType = 'area' AND Area LIKE @SearchTerm)
OR
   (@locationType = 'division' AND xxx_location_division LIKE @SearchTerm)
```

Make sure that `@SearchTerm` starts with/end with `%` -> or use `'%' + @SearchTerm + '%'`.

More info on [LIKE operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

--- Update ----

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM whatever
WHERE
(
  CASE @locationType
     WHEN 'location' THEN account_location
     WHEN 'area' THEN Area
     WHEN 'division' THEN xxx_location_division
  END
) LIKE @SearchTerm
```

Comment: so `LIKE`, `WHERE` AND `CASE` don't go together? also you meant starts with `/` and ends with `%` right?

Comment: yep, my mistake for ==. If you look for places stating with "NEW", then `@SearchTerm` should be "NEW%".

Comment: @FrancoisB. Shocking doesn't not pick the valid area location records using this query.

Comment: `CASE` cannot be used to return a search criteria (for instance `account_location LIKE @SearchTerm`). This how I guess the DB analyse/ understand you query. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you not need to check inbetween string then you can do trick like below :

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM whatever 
WHERE @SearchTerm LIKE 
CASE @locationType 
    WHEN 'location' THEN account_location
    WHEN 'area' THEN Area 
    WHEN 'division' THEN xxx_location_division 
END
```

Or you can do like :

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM whatever 
WHERE 
   (@locationType = 'location' AND account_location LIKE @SearchTerm) 
OR 
   (@locationType = 'area' AND Area LIKE @SearchTerm) 
OR 
   (@locationType = 'division' AND xxx_location_division LIKE @SearchTerm)
```

Comment: the column i search is based on `@searchtype`. haven't mentioned here explicitly but @locationType is the used variable here

Comment: so here you can replace variable @locationType by searchType.