# TSQL: if statement inside a select insert

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, if-statement, case

I have this structure inside a function:

```
INSERT INTO @TheTable
    SELECT DISTINCT

        @Number AS Number,

        @Name AS Name

    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE id = @id
```

I need to add to this structure the result of executing another function and I need your help to do so.

Below the @Name AS Name, line I should add something like this

```
IF (dbo.anotherFunction(@id)==1) 
@NewVisitor AS NewVisitor
ELSE
@NewVisitor AS NoNewVisitor
```

How can I translate this into TSQL??

Thanks a million!

Comment: So your `INSERT` doesn't reference any columns in `MYTABLE` and you bring back as many rows as there are `id` matches then get rid of all but one with `DISTINCT`? You would be much better off just using an `IF EXISTS (...)`

Comment: are newVisitor and noNewVisitor 2 different columns in @TheTable?  So you want to insert @newVisitor into one of 2 columns?

Comment: it's just an example, please teach me how to do the if clause or similar inside that structure. Many thanks

Comment: You'll want a case statement, discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206484/1078151)

Comment: yes Beth, it is like you say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guessing this is what you want...

```
INSERT INTO @TheTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        @Number AS Number,
        @Name AS Name,
        case when (dbo.anotherFunction(@id)=1) then @NewVisitor else null end as NewVisitor,
        case when (dbo.anotherFunction(@id)<>1) then @NewVisitor else null end AS NoNewVisitor
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

IF statements aren't available inside of SELECT statements.  Instead, you'll want to utilize a CASE.

[MSDN Documentation on CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This question makes little sense to me (why all the variables, what do the columns mean?), but you can do it this way:

```
IF (dbo.anotherFunction(@id)==1) 
    INSERT INTO @TheTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        @Number AS Number,
        @Name AS Name,
        @NewVisitor AS NewVisitor
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE id = @id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO @TheTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        @Number AS Number,
        @Name AS Name,
        @NewVisitor AS NoNewVisitor
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE id = @id
```

Alternatively use two CASE statements to selected NewVisitor and NoNewVisitor.