# MS QUERY Syntax correction

Tags: ms-query

Currently I have this query running for me

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.ACCTG_DATE, `Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO, `Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE, `Sheet1$`.JRNL_ID_NO, `Sheet1$`.PRODUCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID, `Sheet1$`.`SUM(DR_CR_AMOUNT)`
FROM `Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
WHERE (`Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE='5092') AND (`Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE Not Like '%H%') AND (`Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO='943776') OR (`Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE='509A') AND (`Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE Not Like '%H%') AND (`Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO='943776')
ORDER BY `Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE
```

The query gives results limited to AGENT_NO='943776'

Whereas I want results which shows

1. ACCT_CODE Not Like '%H%' and
2. If AGENT_NO='943776' then BAL_BOOK_CODE='509A' or BAL_BOOK_CODE='5092'
3. Shows all other AGENT_NO

Comment: Use CASE in Where clause 

Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `Sheet1$`.ACCTG_DATE, `Sheet1$`.JRNL_ID_NO, `Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID, `Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO, `Sheet1$`.PRODUCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE, `Sheet1$`.`SUM(DR_CR_AMOUNT)`
FROM `C:\Documents and Settings\Amit Joshi\Desktop\Book1.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
WHERE (`Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE Not Like '**__H**') AND (`Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO<>'943776')

Union all

SELECT `Sheet1$`.ACCTG_DATE, `Sheet1$`.JRNL_ID_NO, `Sheet1$`.ACCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID, `Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO, `Sheet1$`.PRODUCT_CODE, `Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE, `Sheet1$`.`SUM(DR_CR_AMOUNT)`
FROM `C:\Documents and Settings\Amit Joshi\Desktop\Book1.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
WHERE (`Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE='5092') AND (`Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO='943776') OR (`Sheet1$`.BAL_BOOK_CODE='509A') AND (`Sheet1$`.AGENT_NO='943776')