# Is it possible to decide conditions of an SQL Where clause based on one of the input parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to search for data across three columns. For certain users I search column 1, for other users I search column 1 and 3, and finally for other I look at column 2.

I know I could use a case or if statement and say `if userId = 1 then` run a particular SQL statememnt. But the statement is pretty big, and I don't want to repeat the whole thing every time. Is it possible to use a `CASE` or `IF` statement (or something else) to change the conditions in the `WHERE` part of the statement?

for example, if the company name is x check for value in column 1 or 3, otherwise check in column 2.

I've a very small [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75d4c4/1), but I've no idea where to begin.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause).

Comment: This looks useful, thanks, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add the logic you need in the *where* statement directly using *OR* clauses:

```
[...] WHERE ( company_name = 'x' and (column_1 = @p or column_3 = @p) )
            OR ( company_name <> 'x' and column_2 = @p )
```