# SQL Switch/Case in where clause with NULL value

Tags: sql, switch-statement, case

My question is very similar to [SQL Switch/Case in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484).

I get parameters. If it is excpected that **value** is NULL, I need to get all the values, otherwise I need to filter with **value**.

I'm trying to do this in SQL:

```
    WHERE param 
      CASE
       WHEN #{value} IS NULL THEN {IS NOT NULL}
       ELSE =#{value}
      END
```

How should I correct this SQL request?

```
       WHERE param IS NOT NULL // all values if **value** is NULL
       WHERE param = #{value}  // i.e. value = 'data'
```

Comment: can you explain with example more clearly?

Comment: 'param' is some column in a table, 'value' I get before this request. If value = null I shuold get all values, If for examle value = 'data' I need to filter.

Comment: so if param is null, what do you want to do

Comment: if value is null I do not filter; params is not null

Comment: if the value is null then return all params that are not null?

Comment: Yes, if the value is null then return all params that are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done with logic such as this:

```
where #{value} is NULL or #{value} = param
```

I assume `#{value}` is the value being passed in and `param` is some column in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, if the passed parameter is null then return all rows that the column is not null and if it has value then the ones that has the value. 
Then you should use:

```
where param is NOT NULL OR param = #{value}
```

Comment: In this case I get all values.

Answer (score -1):

i came across similar need. found a solution. thanks to a article on 
https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic

e.g.
declare @param
select *
from blabla
where ( @param is null or blabla.bla_fld = @param )