# SQL Query for 3 table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a 3 table

DiscountHeader Table

```
 HeaderID    HeaderName
 ------------------------
 1            DiscountA
```

DiscountLine table

```
 LineID    HeaderID    Min    Max   DiscountPercentage
 -----------------------------------------------
 1         1           0      1000       1% 
 2         1           1001   2000       2%
```

and  Branch_Totals

```
 CompanyID   HeaderID    Sales_Total      Discount
 ------------------------------------------------------
 B1          1              900              1%
 T2          1             1500              2%
```

And the Company Table

```
 CompanyID    HeaderID
 ------------------------
 B1            1
 T2            1
```

Basically, I would like to give a discount to each company according to their sell figure.

Each company has a Discount HeaderID and each Header has lines. Shows how much discount they will get. More sale, more discount.

for example, CompanyId 1, sold only 900, and they only entitled 1% because it is less than 1000. But companyID 2 sold 1500 and they are entitled 2%

So far i did this

```
 SELECT *
 CASE 
      WHEN B.Sales_Total >V.Min THEN 1
 END AS R
 FROM Branch_Totals B
 JOIN Company H ON H.CompanyID = B.CompanyID 
 JOIN DiscountLine V ON H.VDHeaderID = V.HeaderID
```

But when i said 
WHERE R not null.  IT doesn't work.. Basically "AS R" not acceptable. 
I am not sure how to combine all these tables with a single query.

Comment: What do you mean with "not acceptable"? What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: The column alias is not available in the WHERE clause. Use a derived table.

Comment: What's the question? By the way, missing comma after select *

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause try to use `R IS NOT NULL` like here

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Question is : Can anyone help me to get me the list of comapany with their disocunted rate.

Comment: Sorry actual error is " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'." As Jarlh said I  can't use Column alias in Where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` for this:

```
SELECT B.*, H.*, v.discount
FROM Branch_Totals B JOIn
     Company H
     ON H.CompanyID = B.CompanyID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) v.*
      FROM DiscountLine Vv
      WHERE H.VDHeaderID = V.HeaderID AND
            B.Sales_Total >= V.Min
      ORDER BY V.MIN DESC
     ) v;
```

I notice that you have min and max columns, so you can also just use `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Branch_Totals B JOIN
     Company H 
     ON H.CompanyID = B.CompanyID JOIN
     DiscountLine V
     ON H.VDHeaderID = V.HeaderID AND
        B.Sales_Total BETWEEN v.MIN and v.MAX
```