# How to filter data in SQL based on the availablity of values (in a sequence) in a particular column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know if I am framing the question correctly but let me summarise the problem by giving an example.

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.TYPE IN ('CEO', 'MANAGER', 'LEAD', 'DEVELOPER')
```

Here you can see that all the rows will be returned where the values fall inside the mentioned values.

What I want is that if 'CEO' exists in the table, return the records with CEO only. If not, then return the records with 'MANAGER' and so on.

Based on a sequencing logic, only one record should be returned (based on availability).

Also this is a part of a larger SQL query so if there's a solution where this can be achieved in a single line or two will be helpful.

Comment: Use `CASE` in `WHERE` clause. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause) answers if you don't know logic,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             rank() over (order by case e.type when 'CEO' then 1 when 'MANAGER' then 2 when 'LEAD' then 3 WHEN 'DEVELOPER' then 4 else 5 end) as seqnum
      from e
      where e.TYPE in ('CEO','MANAGER','LEAD','DEVELOPER')
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```